# Store large data into Oracle field

Tags: vb.net, oracle, blob, clob

Can anyone tell me about how to store large data from vb.net to oracle field. I tried in `blob` as well as `clob`. but it is always showing error:

> ORA-01704: string literal too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare
vClob varchar2(32767) := 'very very very.........very very very long text'
begin
update TABLE set FIELD = vClob
```